# Reference to "User Interface" in off-topic close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed

> Questions on **User Interface** are
>   expected to generally relate to **User
>   Interface,** within the scope defined in
>   the faq.

That needs to be changed to User Experience.

Answer (score 1):

Good catch.  I've updated the close reason to say User Experience.